# Error Accessing External Object Property

Tags: powerbuilder

The program has no error during normal runtime mode but when I'm in debugging mode , the error below occurs in any event and in any function. I just can't figure out what exactly or where exactly the error as it only stated in line 0. I also check all the DataWindow that is assigned to DataStore and everything seems correct. I'm running the PowerBuilder 10.2 in Windows 7 64bit OS. Any suggestion or idea?

[image]

Comment: Have you made a fullbuild? Is there any warnings?

Comment: @ DarkinVader, I already did a full build on the target. and there is no warnings.

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually occurs by leaving variables declared in the WATCH mode for DEBUG.

Clean it every application.

[image: Watch - Mode Debug]

Answer (score 0):

I've got [an article](http://www.techno-kitten.com/PowerBuilder_Help/Troubleshooting/Irregular_Behaviour/irregular_behaviour.html) about troubleshooting through "irregular" behaviour like this. One of the items that I had to work through this morning (on someone else's machine) was the fact that he had multiple versions of PB DLLs on his system, and the conflicts were causing odd problems in the IDE which weren't reproducible with the executables. Do a search on PBVM100.DLL and see if you come up with multiple copies with different versions. If you do, clean up the multiple sets of runtimes (not just PBVM, but the *whole set*).

Good luck,

Terry

Answer (score 0):

It's and ancestor problem, try to regenerate all PBLs. If that doesn't work, then probably the function in one of the main PBLs was deleted by accident or the PBL is corrupted, in that case, you should have a back-up PBL.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to share the result in resolving this issue, I've copied first the working PBL from the VM Ware Player then I've paste it in the PB target directory in Win7. I've set a breakpoint inside in one of the window function then triggered the debugging, cleared the variables in the watch window then proceed to debug and fortunately its working.

But I'm kinda worried that this might happen again anytime. Though I practiced to regenerate objects and full build incrementally whenever there are modifications, i think it should be done religiously.

Answer (score -1):

Regenerate every ancestor and its ancestors. also regenerate ancestors of buttons that are being used by your window / functions / buttons/ dw or UO.

Last resolution, do a SaveAs of your window and try again if it will work. Lower versions of powerbuilder sometimes have those bugs.

Comment: i will try on that. I used PB 10.2 by the way.

Comment: I have tried to run other programs in debugging mode and it behaves the same way now.

Comment: I have tried to used Windows XP via VM Ware and run the PB10 developed program in debugging mode and its working fine. PB10.2 is working fine in this mode. There is no error like on the above screenshot. But still need to figure out what is the problem in Win7 64bit.